# Profiling mongoose methods

Tags: node.js, mongodb, coffeescript, mongoose

I want to see logs of calling methods for all my mongoose methods, like this:

```
# Load Book
LoadBook = (id, cb) ->
  console.log 'loading book...'
  Book.findById id, (err, book) ->
    if err
      console.log err
      throw err
    console.log 'loaded book: ' + book.title
    cb book
```

I guess I can define `post` and `pre` methods like this:

```
BookSchema.pre 'save', (next) ->
  console.log 'loading ' + `model_name(don't know how to get it)` + ' ...'
  next()
```

And the same for other methods like `findById` or `remove` but it's long. And the error handling works only if I don't use callbacks, but I use it every time. I mean:

```
Part.on 'error', (err) ->
  console.log "Got an error", err
```

I think it doesn't work when there is a callback, does it?
Perhaps there is some universal profiler in nodejs? I'm using express by the way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can [enable debug logging](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/faq.html) in Mongoose by calling:

```
mongoose.set('debug', true);
```

With that enabled you'll get a log entry for every MongoDB operation made via Mongoose.  Not sure if it's exactly what you want, but it's worth giving it a try.

Comment: Great, Thanks! No idea how I miss that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`look`](https://github.com/baryshev/look) module to profile your node.js app. It based on [nodetime](https://nodetime.com) but works on local server.

Comment: I guess it's not working with coffee, throw an error. But nodetime works, now I figure out how(I had installed it few days ago, but can't found any info about logging)

Comment: Thanks for error report. I will check it. Are you trying to collect cpu profile with nodetime?

Comment: There are 3 tabs: Requests | Operations | Errors , and it shows me only `Operations` that contains templates, styles and js files transfer to client from server. Perhaps because other info placed in other files.

Comment: I just fix coffescript support in `look`, you can try it again. I think, you need to use `Cpu profiler`, not `Transactions`. http://gyazo.com/884993ba26fe72cecbaabb58a40a1fb8

Comment: Thanks, now it works. The problem with with request parhaps because I'm using angularJS on client.